# Cálculo acumulado por cifras parecidas

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo que hacer una vista en sql server, un query que me haga acumulado de pérdida por una duración de parada, adjunto pantallazo de la tabla de datos productos y también el resultado como quiero, pero la condición es que solo debe sumar si los días son consecutivos, si hay mas de un día no lo debo tener en cuenta, y cuya duración sea igual a 24 horas, palabras mas y palabras menos, adjunto imagen del excel manual que hago bajando los datos de sql y lo que que quiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```sql
SELECT 
    AAA.CONTADOR,
    AAA.PRODUCTO,
    AAA.FECHA,
    AAA.DURACION_PARADA,
    AAA.ARROZ_PERDIDO
FROM
(
    SELECT
        PRODUCTO,
        FECHA,
        DURACION_PARADA,
        ARROZ_PERDIDO,
        DATEDIFF(HH, (LAG(FECHA) OVER (order by start_Datetime)), FECHA) AS CONTADOR
    FROM MASTER_PRODUCTOS
    WHERE PRODUCTO = 'ARROZ_1'
    AND START_DATETIME >= '2021-01-01'
) AS AAA
WHERE AAA.DIF_HORAS IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY AAA.FECHA ASC
```

```
CREATE TABLE MASTER_PRODUCTOS(
    CONTADOR        VARCHAR(100),
    PRODUCTO        VARCHAR(10),
    FECHA           date,
    DURACION_PARADA float,
    ARROZ_PERDIDO   float);
    
INSERT INTO MASTER_PRODUCTOS
VALUES  
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '17-Jan-2021', '4',     '76.98' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '18-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '19-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '20-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '21-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '22-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '23-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '24-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '25-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '26-Jan-2021', '24',    '461.9' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '27-Jan-2021', '18.17', '349.7' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '30-Jan-2021', '2.65',  '69.62' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '06-Mar-2021', '1.17',  '32.86' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '17-Mar-2021', '2.03',  '57.02' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '01-Apr-2021', '1.45',  '40.73' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '12-Apr-2021', '5',     '140.44'),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '27-Apr-2021', '1.88',  '37.98' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '03-May-2021', '4.45',  '83.86' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '06-May-2021', '3.23',  '60.87' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '07-May-2021', '1.5',   '28.27' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '19-Jun-2021', '1.67',  '22.81' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '25-Jun-2021', '4.7',   '64.19' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '30-Jun-2021', '2.08',  '28.41' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '21-Jul-2021', '5.42',  '74.03' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '22-Jul-2021', '24',    '327.8' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '23-Jul-2021', '24',    '327.8' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '24-Jul-2021', '24',    '327.8' ),
    ('1 DIA'        , 'ARROZ_1', '25-Jul-2021', '15',    '204.88'),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '28-Jul-2021', '4.67',  '63.78' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '12-Aug-2021', '3.52',  '53.06' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '29-Aug-2021', '3.3',   '54.33' ),
    ('MAS DE UN DIA', 'ARROZ_1', '11-Sep-2021', '6.97',  '115.73');
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner los datos como texto y no como imagen? Es para que podamos trabajar sobre datos de prueba y dar soluciones que funcionen.

Comment: hola, no se como compartirte los datos, se puede enviar por correo?

Comment: No, los pones como texto. Puedes exportar el archivo de Excel a csv y copiar el texto. También puedes usar la opción "Text to DDL" de [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para convertirlo a código que pueda ser ejecutado más fácilmente.

Comment: Entre los requisitos especificas: "cuya duración sea igual a 24 horas" pero en la foto tomas dos filas con DURACION_PARADA != 24. No me queda claro porque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de agrupar las filas consecutivas (en este caso aquellas filas cuya fecha es consecutiva) se conoce como "Problema de brechas e islas".

En este caso en la primer subquery identifico las islas (en función de las fechas consecutivas). Todos aquellos registros que quedan con el mismo número de `ISLA` pertenecen a la misma isla. Luego agrupo por `PRODUCTO` e `ISLA` y sumo el `ARROZ_PERDIDO`.

No me queda claro si además tengo que agregar la restricción `DURACION_PARADA = 24` en la primer subquery.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FECHA) - CONVERT(INT, CAST(FECHA as DATETIME)) AS ISLA
             FROM MASTER_PRODUCTOS
             WHERE PRODUCTO = 'ARROZ_1' AND FECHA >= '2021-01-01' AND CONTADOR = '1 DIA')
             
SELECT PRODUCTO, MIN(FECHA) AS FECHA, SUM(ARROZ_PERDIDO) AS ARROZ_PERDIDO
FROM cte
GROUP BY PRODUCTO, ISLA
ORDER BY PRODUCTO, MIN(FECHA);
```

Calculando la columna `CONTADOR`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,
                    DATEDIFF(HH, (LAG(FECHA) OVER (order by FECHA)), FECHA) AS CONTADOR,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FECHA) - CONVERT(INT, CAST(FECHA as DATETIME)) AS ISLA
             FROM MASTER_PRODUCTOS
             WHERE PRODUCTO = 'ARROZ_1' AND FECHA >= '2021-01-01')
             
SELECT PRODUCTO, MIN(FECHA) AS FECHA, SUM(ARROZ_PERDIDO) AS ARROZ_PERDIDO
FROM cte
WHERE CONTADOR = 24
GROUP BY PRODUCTO, ISLA
ORDER BY PRODUCTO, MIN(FECHA);
```

Comment: hola nachospiu, ya esa seria la respuesta, lo unico malo es que como le hago para que el query primero me calcule el contador, ese me toca hay manualmente y no sabria como calcularlo, la idea es que me diga un dia si la fecha del registro se puede comparar con la fecha anteror y que me diga si tiene un dia, o mas de un dia. seria lo unico que me haria falta

Comment: Hola @SadidLeonardo!!! Agregué una segunda query que calcula la columna `CONTADOR` (siempre excluye la primer fila de cada `ISLA`, porque con la fila anterior tiene mas de 24 hs). Además las filas del 6 y 7 de mayo son consecutivas, así que también las retorna. Si no entendí bien algo me lo hace saber.

Comment: muchas gracias nachospiu, me ahorras 3 horas de trabajo diario, pues todos los dias tengo que hacero con varios productos en un excel, instale una base de datos sql server pequeña la cual voy alimentando todos los dias, pero no sabia como hacer esto, muchas gracias por la ayuda................ saludos

Comment: De nada @SadidLeonardo!!!! Me alegra que mi query te haya sido util.